# NPM- ERR Registry error parsing json

Tags: angular, npm

when I run NPM install..I keep getting an error..it can't be from package.json ( i create a project using --- ng new projectname) I spent hours looking for a solution with no luck. also i went to "https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/common-errors"

[image]

[image]

I tried many thing such as

- npm config rm proxy
- npm config rm https-proxy
- rm -f package-lock.json && npm install --- I get error 'RM' not
  recognized
- npm config get registry prints: https://registry.npmjs.org/
- npm config set strict-ssl false

also when I run

- npm config get registry => i get http://registry.npmjs.org/
- npm config get http-proxy =>i get undefined
- npm config get https-proxy =>i get null

Comment: Have you tried updating npm? Version 5.6.0 is the current version.

Comment: i tried (npm install npm@latest -g) and got the same error

Comment: also tried npm update -g   --same error

Comment: I ran the same install command you did. The install succeeded. I even installed ngx-order-pipe because installing the ng2-order-pipe install gave a message to start using the ngx version instead. Both worked. Are you running as admin when you try?

Comment: yes, ran it as an admin and got the same error

Comment: also uninstalled nodejs and re-installed again

Comment: updated my issue with a better error message

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy or firewall? In the html response the title is `Access to this site is blocked` so the npm cannot connect to the npm registry

Comment: I see that too. Websense seems to be the thing preventing this from working.

Comment: this is strange...this is not the first time i create such applications...Initially I thought it is something with the application i am developing..so after hours i have decided to create a new one to narrow down the issue just like what you see above and got the same error page..this was not happening few days back.. not sure how to move forward

Comment: yes, I confirm when I am nt logged in to the network ....everything works...how can I resolve this issue..proxy/firewall

Comment: @rgoal i have tried many things...updating/uninstalling many things. finally this idea of disconnect internet and run this command worked.